# Max in a list with two conditions

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list in Python in which each element is a tuple like this:

```
(attr1, attr2, attr3)
```

I want to find the tuple that has the largest `attr2`, but that have `attr3 >= 100`.

What is the pythonic approach to this?

Comment: and what output would you expect if all values have `attr3 < 100`? `max()` will raise a ValueError if it receives an empty sequence.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to both filter and use a `key` argument to max:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(filter(lambda a: a[2] >= 100, yourlist), key=itemgetter(1))
```

The filter can also be expressed as a generator expression:

```
max((t for t in yourlist if t[2] >= 100), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourlist = [(1, 2, 300), (2, 3, 400), (3, 6, 50)]
>>> max((t for t in yourlist if t[2] >= 100), key=itemgetter(1))
(2, 3, 400)
>>> max(filter(lambda a: a[2] >= 100, yourlist), key=itemgetter(1))
(2, 3, 400)
```

Note that because you filter, it's easy to end up with an empty list to pick the max from, so you may need to catch `ValueError`s unless you need that exception to propagate up the call stack:

```
try:
    return max(filter(lambda a: a[2] >= 100, yourlist), key=itemgetter(1))
except ValueError:
    # Return a default
    return (0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @wim: `filter()` fits in very well with the `max()` functional pattern. It's a question of taste here.

Comment: You'll also need to handle `ValueError` thrown by `max()` if the generator/filter returns an empty sequence.

Comment: @ShawnChin: That isn't specific to generator or filter use. `max([])` also throws that exception.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was merely pointing out the edge-case in the OP's requirements and suggesting an approach to make your solution more robust.

Comment: @ShawnChin: Yeah, the filter makes it more likely to run into this, I've added it to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the index of the maximum value you could do:

```
 max(filter(lambda a: a[1][2] >= 100, enumerate(yourlist)), key=lambda x:x[1][1])`
```

although I have to admit that it gets a bit unreadable.