# max-Function for attributes of objects

Tags: python, list, max

I wonder, what might be the most pythonic way to use `max` on a list of objects regarding a specific attribute. Assume there is this class:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Now there is a list of `Foo`s:

```
foos = [Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(1)]
```

I want to have the maximum *value* of this list.

I could use `max` on a list:

```
max_value = max([foo.value for foo in foos])
```

This would always construct a list first (might reduce performance on huge lists), so I thought of using the `key` argument:

```
max_value = max(foos, key=lambda foo: foo.value).value
```

This looks a bit ugly to me, since I don’t get the attribute, but the object.

I could also define the `__eq__`, `__le__` functions inside `Foo`, but this would limit the use of `max` to a specific value, I could not use `max` for more than one attribute.

Is there another way, to get the maximum value in a nice pythonic way?

Comment: Generic programming advice is off-topic for Code Review. We would be glad to review code in the context of a real application.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. When I posted this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57804/ on SO, I was told, it should be moved here, that’s why I thought, this is the right place. Is there a SE-site for problems like this?

Comment: Due to the similarity with [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12459656/1157100), I've migrated this question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slightly better with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
max_value = max(foo.value for foo in foos)
# instead of:
# max_value = max([foo.value for foo in foos])
```

This is plenty Pythonic, not sure if it can get any better than this.